# What is the CF OnRequest scope called in other languages?

Tags: php, node.js, asp.net, wordpress, coldfusion

I've been fortunate enough to be a CF dev for pretty much my entire IT career without having to take on using another development language so I have a knowledge hole I'd like to ask others to help me with.

I've built an API and I want to describe to others how to invoke it.  It needs to be invoked first thing during a request before any generated content is sent back to the user.  One of the possible outcomes of the API call is that the incoming user request could be aborted so that there's no error message but also no generated content.  Just a blank screen.  Sending back the blank screen with no generated page code is critical.

I can tell someone using CF that it needs to be called at the beginning of the Request scope or OnRequest scope but I'm at a loss as to how to get across the same arrangement for someone using other languages/frameworks like PHP, ASP.NET, Node.js, Wordpress, etc.

So, for example, for a CF based site I'd say something like: "The synchronous API call needs to be made early in the Request or OnRequest scope and BEFORE any generated page content is returned to the user".  What I'm looking for is how to describe that same thing but for users of those other languages/frameworks.

Odd question but Google has been zero help (or perhaps I just don't know how to search for something like this).  Any advice/guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't worry about other language terminology.  Just tell the programmers what those scopes are and let them worry about how to find equivalents in their progamming languages.

Comment: Dan's advice is solid. Also the ColdFusion lifecycle event handlers (not "scopes", scopes are a different thing entirely) are part of the CF application server, not the CFML language. Other languages won't have such concepts (PHP has no concept of an "application" in the CF sense of the term) as they're *languages* not app servers. Perhaps point them @ https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/designing-and-optimizing-a-coldfusion-application/defining-the-application-and-its-event-handlers-in-application-c.html - which explains what's going on.

Comment: @DanBracuk - The trouble is that I'm needing to provide direction to potentially non-tech folk for where to place the API call on their sites.  If the target audience were technical people, no problem.

Comment: @AdamCameron - Event handlers, yes.  I should have been more precise.  So, do other languages/frameworks have an equivalent to the OnRequest or Request event handlers like we have in the app scope?

Comment: Well: it's not a great question, if I'm to be honest. It's not very focused, uses incorrect terminology (and even now you know that, you've not updated the Q!). I did not - for the record - downvote it, but I can understand why it has been.

Comment: @AdamCameron Incorrect terminology how?  I mean, I'm coming back to this nearly 6 months later (I do appreciate mentioning you weren't the one to downvote this) and I'd made clear I've worked in CF practically exclusively.  The CF terminology is accurate.  What might I have said if I'd had a knowledge of other languages that might have made it more accurate?

I'm at the point where I'm writing an install/usage guide for what's turned into a web service.  Still needs to be called first thing and I am incorporating the comments and advice from the answers to my question here.

Answer (score 1):

Is not the answer to your question simply to tell them "It needs to be invoked first thing during a request before any generated content is sent back to the user" (I copy and pasted that from your question).

That's it. That is absolutely clear.

That's all you need to do.

Don't worry about *how* they need to do that in their language of choice, esp given the very nature of your question, you won't know how. It's *their* job to write the code to consume your API. Not yours.

At most you could give them some usage pseudo-code along the lines of:

```
// at the beginning of the response handler

apiResult = apiObj.makeRequest(args, here)
if (apiResult.youCanComeIn == false) {
    // handle it with a 403 or something appropriate
    // stop
}

// they're allowed in, so rest of processing here
```

Comment: I suppose but what I'd like to do is to remove any impediments to making use of it.  I've been a dev/DBA for going on 25 years now and if there's one thing I've learned to do it's not expect too much from your user base.  The adage of "if you make something idiot proof, the universe will just make a better idiot" has been proven to me time and again.  I may end up doing as you suggested but I'd like to be able to have examples on hand for how to implement it when I get someone who doesn't know what they're doing.

Comment: That is not your responsibility. Your responsibility is to expose the API for consumption. Your sample implementation could just be pseudocode. Do you expect google to give you CFML code for how to consume their APIs? No. Do you just get on with reading the docs? I bet you do. Same with everyone else.

Comment: I appreciate the advice but I already know it's not something I'm REQUIRED to do...it's something I'd like to do.  The service this API provides is partially targeted at small businesses who may lack the technical expertise to know how to consume it so if I'm able to provide code examples, that'd be helpful if for no other reason than it gets them that much closer to choosing to subscribe.

Thanks for the replies.  I appreciate the insights.

Comment: Well, it turns out my original concern has been realized.  The people wanting to make use of the REST API I built aren't technical and so the "it's not my responsibility" advice turns out to be s**t.  This is the difference between being a dev and business owner.  Devs can be blithe, business owner...not so much.

Comment: It is simply *not* your the provider of an API to ensure the capabilities of their consumers. That these people in a technical role - which consuming APIs is - aren't technical is _their_ problem. Not yours. You are not responsible for this. This is not a tech vs business thing, this is just a "functioning in reality" thing. "It needs to be invoked first thing during a request before any generated content is sent back to the user" is 101 level guidance. "at the beginning" is not a complicated or technical concept. What exact actual guidance/documentation did you give them?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, any API request must return a specific response. And probably you need to pass the expected value and the value of a certain error at the level of your API. Further, any developer will understand what information to issue when receiving some error from the API response.

You probably mean something like: "request processing is required on the server side, in case of an error, generate an empty page on the client side", etc.

*It's hard to recommend anything. Maybe `server-side rendering, SSR`*

Comment: The API will return a response.  It's that response that the user needs to act on and that "acting on" needs to be BEFORE they generate any page content for their site visitor.